# Implementing a Lookup Table

Tags: c++, algorithm, indexing, lookup, lookup-tables

I am working on a custom data structure and I am currently in the beta testing process: The data will be stored within an array and this array can be represented as a 4D, 2D & 1D array. These three arrays are declared within a union since it represents the same memory addressing. Here is the declaration to my class:

**SomeClass.h**

```
#ifndef SomeClass_H
#define SomeClass_H

class SomeClass {
public:
    static const unsigned V1D_SIZE;   // Single Or Linear Array Representation : Size 256 - 256 Elements
    static const unsigned V2D_SIZE;   // 2D Array [16][16]                     : Size 16  - 256 Elements
    static const unsigned V4D_SIZE;   // 4D Array [4][4][4][4]                 : Size 4   - 256 Elements

    enum Index {
        HEX_UNDER_FLOW = -0x01,
        HEX_0 = 0x00,
        HEX_1 = 0x01,
        HEX_2 = 0x02,
        HEX_3 = 0x03,
        HEX_4 = 0x04,
        HEX_5 = 0x05,
        HEX_6 = 0x06,
        HEX_7 = 0x07,
        HEX_8 = 0x08,
        HEX_9 = 0x09,
        HEX_A = 0x0A,
        HEX_B = 0x0B,
        HEX_C = 0x0C,
        HEX_D = 0x0D,
        HEX_E = 0x0E,
        HEX_F = 0x0F,
        HEX_OVER_FLOW = 0x10
    }; // Index

    // Will Be Private After Testing.
    union {
        int m_p256[256];
        int m_p16[16][16];
        int m_p4[4][4][4][4];
    };

private:
    struct CrossReference {
        Index A;
        Index B;

        CrossReference() {}
        CrossReference( const Index& A_, const Index& B_ ) : A(A_), B(B_) {}
    } typedef CR;


    // Current Not Used Only Here To Illustrate A Simple Representation - May Use Or Incorporate Later
    struct Cubes {
        unsigned box;     // 0 - 3    - w
        unsigned slice;   // 0 - 15   - z 
        unsigned row;     // 0 - 15   - y
        unsigned coloumn; // 0 - 15   - x
    } m_cubes;


    CR m_cr[256];

public: 
    SomeClass();
    ~SomeClass();

    const CR& getIndexTable() const;
    void displayIndexTable() const;

private:
    // Must Be Called In Constructor First!
    void initializeCrossReference();

}; // SomeClass

#endif // SomeClass
```

I need to generate a reference look up table of coordinate value pairs of this 4D structure to implement its 1D version.

To illustrate the index traversal you can refer to these images for a visual representation:

[image: 3D Visual] Note: the {x,y,z,w} in this image does not represent the actual 4D array in memory: it is just a visualization! In Memory the 4D array would be as this: `array[box][slice][row][column]` and this image represents 1 box within the 4D array.

[image: 2D Visual 1D LookUp] Note: This image is a 2D visual representation of all 4 boxes that are described in the top image. The colored text in both images correspond to the appropriate index.

The second image is a 2D flat grid image representation of this 4D array data structure. We can use this image to generate the coordinates for this look up table.

Each quarter of this image represents 1 box. Top Left (starting) is box 0, top right box 1, bottom left box 2, bottom right box 3. Each box, can be broken down the same way for each slice. Top Left (starting) slice 0, top right slice 1, bottom left slice 2, bottom right slice 3. Then when working in each slice the traversal is row - col and once col = 3, we move down to the next row. So after we complete a single slice we have to jump our location depending on the current slices index. The same goes for boxes.

Here are a couple of examples of traversing this table to generate a set of index coordinate values in hex notation:

```
array[2][3][0][1] our [A,B] hex value would be [0x0C, 0x05] 
array[1][1][3][3] our [A,B] hex value would be [0x03, 0x0F]
```

I am in the process of designing a function to generate this look up table. I have done this manually here:

```
void SomeClass::initializeCrossReference() {
    //////////////////////////////////
    // Upper Half Of Grid Structure //
    //////////////////////////////////  

    //  Grid Coordinates //
    // Linear Or 1D Array Representation - Mapped From type[16][16] which is a 
    // 2D Compressed Version of type[4][4][4][4] - 
    // NOTE: This does not represent 4D Space; it represents a cluster of 4 (3D Cubes). 
    // In the declaration of the class there are two multi deminsional arrays that
    // are shared in memory through a nameless union.

    //      ROW              COL          

    // BOX - 0
    // Slice - 0
    // Row - 0                              // Column Coordinates
    m_cr[0].A  = HEX_0;  m_cr[0].B = HEX_0;  // col 0
    m_cr[1].A  = HEX_0;  m_cr[1].B = HEX_1;  // col 1
    m_cr[2].A  = HEX_0;  m_cr[2].B = HEX_2;  // col 2
    m_cr[3].A  = HEX_0;  m_cr[3].B = HEX_3;  // col 3
    // Row - 1
    m_cr[4].A  = HEX_1;  m_cr[4].B = HEX_0;
    m_cr[5].A  = HEX_1;  m_cr[5].B = HEX_1;
    m_cr[6].A  = HEX_1;  m_cr[6].B = HEX_2;
    m_cr[7].A  = HEX_1;  m_cr[7].B = HEX_3;
    // Row - 2
    m_cr[8].A  = HEX_2;  m_cr[8].B  = HEX_0;
    m_cr[9].A  = HEX_2;  m_cr[9].B  = HEX_1;
    m_cr[10].A = HEX_2;  m_cr[10].B = HEX_2;
    m_cr[11].A = HEX_2;  m_cr[11].B = HEX_3;
    // Row - 3
    m_cr[12].A = HEX_3;  m_cr[12].B = HEX_0;    
    m_cr[13].A = HEX_3;  m_cr[13].B = HEX_1;
    m_cr[14].A = HEX_3;  m_cr[14].B = HEX_2;
    m_cr[15].A = HEX_3;  m_cr[15].B = HEX_3;

    // Slice - 1
    // Row - 0
    m_cr[16].A = HEX_0;  m_cr[16].B = HEX_4;
    m_cr[17].A = HEX_0;  m_cr[17].B = HEX_5;
    m_cr[18].A = HEX_0;  m_cr[18].B = HEX_6;    
    m_cr[19].A = HEX_0;  m_cr[19].B = HEX_7;
    // Row - 1
    m_cr[20].A = HEX_1;  m_cr[20].B = HEX_4;
    m_cr[21].A = HEX_1;  m_cr[21].B = HEX_5;
    m_cr[22].A = HEX_1;  m_cr[22].B = HEX_6;
    m_cr[23].A = HEX_1;  m_cr[23].B = HEX_7;
    // Row - 2;
    m_cr[24].A = HEX_2;  m_cr[24].B = HEX_4;
    m_cr[25].A = HEX_2;  m_cr[25].B = HEX_5;
    m_cr[26].A = HEX_2;  m_cr[26].B = HEX_6;
    m_cr[27].A = HEX_2;  m_cr[27].B = HEX_7;
    // Row - 3
    m_cr[28].A = HEX_3;  m_cr[28].B = HEX_4;
    m_cr[29].A = HEX_3;  m_cr[29].B = HEX_5;
    m_cr[30].A = HEX_3;  m_cr[30].B = HEX_6;
    m_cr[31].A = HEX_3;  m_cr[31].B = HEX_7;

    // Slice - 2
    // Row - 0
    m_cr[32].A = HEX_4;  m_cr[32].B = HEX_0;
    m_cr[33].A = HEX_4;  m_cr[33].B = HEX_1;
    m_cr[34].A = HEX_4;  m_cr[34].B = HEX_2;
    m_cr[35].A = HEX_4;  m_cr[35].B = HEX_3;
    // Row - 1;
    m_cr[36].A = HEX_5;  m_cr[36].B = HEX_0;
    m_cr[37].A = HEX_5;  m_cr[37].B = HEX_1;
    m_cr[38].A = HEX_5;  m_cr[38].B = HEX_2;
    m_cr[39].A = HEX_5;  m_cr[39].B = HEX_3;
    // Row - 2;
    m_cr[40].A = HEX_6;  m_cr[40].B = HEX_0;
    m_cr[41].A = HEX_6;  m_cr[41].B = HEX_1;
    m_cr[42].A = HEX_6;  m_cr[42].B = HEX_2;
    m_cr[43].A = HEX_6;  m_cr[43].B = HEX_3;
    // Row - 3
    m_cr[44].A = HEX_7;  m_cr[44].B = HEX_0;
    m_cr[45].A = HEX_7;  m_cr[45].B = HEX_1;
    m_cr[46].A = HEX_7;  m_cr[46].B = HEX_2;
    m_cr[47].A = HEX_7;  m_cr[47].B = HEX_3;

    // Slice - 3
    // Row - 0
    m_cr[48].A = HEX_4;  m_cr[48].B = HEX_4;
    m_cr[49].A = HEX_4;  m_cr[49].B = HEX_5;
    m_cr[50].A = HEX_4;  m_cr[50].B = HEX_6;
    m_cr[51].A = HEX_4;  m_cr[51].B = HEX_7;
    // Row - 1
    m_cr[52].A = HEX_5;  m_cr[52].B = HEX_4;
    m_cr[53].A = HEX_5;  m_cr[53].B = HEX_5;
    m_cr[54].A = HEX_5;  m_cr[54].B = HEX_6;
    m_cr[55].A = HEX_5;  m_cr[55].B = HEX_7;
    // Row - 2;
    m_cr[56].A = HEX_6;  m_cr[56].B = HEX_4;
    m_cr[57].A = HEX_6;  m_cr[57].B = HEX_5;
    m_cr[58].A = HEX_6;  m_cr[58].B = HEX_6;
    m_cr[59].A = HEX_6;  m_cr[59].B = HEX_7;
    // Row - 3
    m_cr[60].A = HEX_7;  m_cr[60].B = HEX_4;
    m_cr[61].A = HEX_7;  m_cr[61].B = HEX_5;
    m_cr[62].A = HEX_7;  m_cr[62].B = HEX_6;
    m_cr[63].A = HEX_7;  m_cr[63].B = HEX_7;

    // BOX - 1
    // Slice - 0
    // Row - 0
    m_cr[64].A = HEX_0;  m_cr[64].B = HEX_8;
    m_cr[65].A = HEX_0;  m_cr[65].B = HEX_9;
    m_cr[66].A = HEX_0;  m_cr[66].B = HEX_A;
    m_cr[67].A = HEX_0;  m_cr[67].B = HEX_B;
    // Row - 1
    m_cr[68].A = HEX_1;  m_cr[68].B = HEX_8;
    m_cr[69].A = HEX_1;  m_cr[69].B = HEX_9;
    m_cr[70].A = HEX_1;  m_cr[70].B = HEX_A;
    m_cr[71].A = HEX_1;  m_cr[71].B = HEX_B;
    // Row - 2
    m_cr[72].A = HEX_2;  m_cr[72].B = HEX_8;
    m_cr[73].A = HEX_2;  m_cr[73].B = HEX_9;
    m_cr[74].A = HEX_2;  m_cr[74].B = HEX_A;
    m_cr[75].A = HEX_2;  m_cr[75].B = HEX_B;
    // Row - 3
    m_cr[76].A = HEX_3;  m_cr[76].B = HEX_8;
    m_cr[77].A = HEX_3;  m_cr[77].B = HEX_9;
    m_cr[78].A = HEX_3;  m_cr[78].B = HEX_A;
    m_cr[79].A = HEX_3;  m_cr[79].B = HEX_B;

    // Slice - 1
    // Row - 0
    m_cr[80].A = HEX_0;  m_cr[80].B = HEX_C;
    m_cr[81].A = HEX_0;  m_cr[81].B = HEX_D;
    m_cr[82].A = HEX_0;  m_cr[82].B = HEX_E;
    m_cr[83].A = HEX_0;  m_cr[83].B = HEX_F;
    // Row - 1
    m_cr[84].A = HEX_1;  m_cr[84].B = HEX_C;
    m_cr[85].A = HEX_1;  m_cr[85].B = HEX_D;
    m_cr[86].A = HEX_1;  m_cr[86].B = HEX_E;
    m_cr[87].A = HEX_1;  m_cr[87].B = HEX_F;
    // Row - 2
    m_cr[88].A = HEX_2;  m_cr[88].B = HEX_C;
    m_cr[89].A = HEX_2;  m_cr[89].B = HEX_D;
    m_cr[90].A = HEX_2;  m_cr[90].B = HEX_E;
    m_cr[91].A = HEX_2;  m_cr[91].B = HEX_F;
    // Row - 3
    m_cr[92].A = HEX_3;  m_cr[92].B = HEX_C;
    m_cr[93].A = HEX_3;  m_cr[93].B = HEX_D;
    m_cr[94].A = HEX_3;  m_cr[94].B = HEX_E;
    m_cr[95].A = HEX_3;  m_cr[95].B = HEX_F;

    // Slice - 2
    // Row - 0
    m_cr[96].A = HEX_4;  m_cr[96].B = HEX_8;
    m_cr[97].A = HEX_4;  m_cr[97].B = HEX_9;
    m_cr[98].A = HEX_4;  m_cr[98].B = HEX_A;
    m_cr[99].A = HEX_4;  m_cr[99].B = HEX_B;
    // Row - 1
    m_cr[100].A = HEX_5;  m_cr[100].B = HEX_8;
    m_cr[101].A = HEX_5;  m_cr[101].B = HEX_9;
    m_cr[102].A = HEX_5;  m_cr[102].B = HEX_A;
    m_cr[103].A = HEX_5;  m_cr[103].B = HEX_B;
    // Row - 2
    m_cr[104].A = HEX_6;  m_cr[104].B = HEX_8;
    m_cr[105].A = HEX_6;  m_cr[105].B = HEX_9;
    m_cr[106].A = HEX_6;  m_cr[106].B = HEX_A;
    m_cr[107].A = HEX_6;  m_cr[107].B = HEX_B;
    // Row - 3
    m_cr[108].A = HEX_7;  m_cr[108].B = HEX_8;
    m_cr[109].A = HEX_7;  m_cr[109].B = HEX_9;
    m_cr[110].A = HEX_7;  m_cr[110].B = HEX_A;
    m_cr[111].A = HEX_7;  m_cr[111].B = HEX_B;

    // Slice - 3
    // Row - 0
    m_cr[112].A = HEX_4;  m_cr[112].B = HEX_C;
    m_cr[113].A = HEX_4;  m_cr[113].B = HEX_D;
    m_cr[114].A = HEX_4;  m_cr[114].B = HEX_E;
    m_cr[115].A = HEX_4;  m_cr[115].B = HEX_F;
    // Row - 1
    m_cr[116].A = HEX_5;  m_cr[116].B = HEX_C;
    m_cr[117].A = HEX_5;  m_cr[117].B = HEX_D;
    m_cr[118].A = HEX_5;  m_cr[118].B = HEX_E;
    m_cr[119].A = HEX_5;  m_cr[119].B = HEX_F;
    // Row - 2
    m_cr[120].A = HEX_6;  m_cr[120].B = HEX_C;
    m_cr[121].A = HEX_6;  m_cr[121].B = HEX_D;
    m_cr[122].A = HEX_6;  m_cr[122].B = HEX_E;
    m_cr[123].A = HEX_6;  m_cr[123].B = HEX_F;
    // Row - 3
    m_cr[124].A = HEX_7;  m_cr[124].B = HEX_C;
    m_cr[125].A = HEX_7;  m_cr[125].B = HEX_D;
    m_cr[126].A = HEX_7;  m_cr[126].B = HEX_E;
    m_cr[127].A = HEX_7;  m_cr[127].B = HEX_F;

    //////////////////////////////////
    // Lower Half Of Grid Structure //
    //////////////////////////////////

    // Box - 2
    // Slice - 0
    // Row - 0
    m_cr[128].A = HEX_8;  m_cr[128].B = HEX_0;  // col 0
    m_cr[129].A = HEX_8;  m_cr[129].B = HEX_1;  // col 1
    m_cr[130].A = HEX_8;  m_cr[130].B = HEX_2;  // col 2
    m_cr[131].A = HEX_8;  m_cr[131].B = HEX_3;  // col 3
    // Row - 1
    m_cr[132].A = HEX_9;  m_cr[132].B = HEX_0;
    m_cr[133].A = HEX_9;  m_cr[133].B = HEX_1;
    m_cr[134].A = HEX_9;  m_cr[134].B = HEX_2;
    m_cr[135].A = HEX_9;  m_cr[135].B = HEX_3;
    // Row - 2
    m_cr[136].A = HEX_A;  m_cr[136].B = HEX_0;
    m_cr[137].A = HEX_A;  m_cr[137].B = HEX_1;
    m_cr[138].A = HEX_A;  m_cr[138].B = HEX_2;
    m_cr[139].A = HEX_A;  m_cr[139].B = HEX_3;
    // Row - 3
    m_cr[140].A = HEX_B;  m_cr[140].B = HEX_0;
    m_cr[141].A = HEX_B;  m_cr[141].B = HEX_1;
    m_cr[142].A = HEX_B;  m_cr[142].B = HEX_2;
    m_cr[143].A = HEX_B;  m_cr[143].B = HEX_3;

    // Slice - 1
    // Row - 0
    m_cr[144].A = HEX_8;  m_cr[144].B = HEX_4;
    m_cr[145].A = HEX_8;  m_cr[145].B = HEX_5;
    m_cr[146].A = HEX_8;  m_cr[146].B = HEX_6;
    m_cr[147].A = HEX_8;  m_cr[147].B = HEX_7;
    // Row - 1
    m_cr[148].A = HEX_9;  m_cr[148].B = HEX_4;
    m_cr[149].A = HEX_9;  m_cr[149].B = HEX_5;
    m_cr[150].A = HEX_9;  m_cr[150].B = HEX_6;
    m_cr[151].A = HEX_9;  m_cr[151].B = HEX_7;
    // Row - 2;
    m_cr[152].A = HEX_A;  m_cr[152].B = HEX_4;
    m_cr[153].A = HEX_A;  m_cr[153].B = HEX_5;
    m_cr[154].A = HEX_A;  m_cr[154].B = HEX_6;
    m_cr[155].A = HEX_A;  m_cr[155].B = HEX_7;
    // Row - 3
    m_cr[156].A = HEX_B;  m_cr[156].B = HEX_4;
    m_cr[157].A = HEX_B;  m_cr[157].B = HEX_5;
    m_cr[158].A = HEX_B;  m_cr[158].B = HEX_6;
    m_cr[159].A = HEX_B;  m_cr[159].B = HEX_7;

    // Slice - 2
    // Row - 0
    m_cr[160].A = HEX_C;  m_cr[160].B = HEX_0;
    m_cr[161].A = HEX_C;  m_cr[161].B = HEX_1;
    m_cr[162].A = HEX_C;  m_cr[162].B = HEX_2;
    m_cr[163].A = HEX_C;  m_cr[163].B = HEX_3;
    // Row - 1;
    m_cr[164].A = HEX_D;  m_cr[164].B = HEX_0;
    m_cr[165].A = HEX_D;  m_cr[165].B = HEX_1;
    m_cr[166].A = HEX_D;  m_cr[166].B = HEX_2;
    m_cr[167].A = HEX_D;  m_cr[167].B = HEX_3;
    // Row - 2;
    m_cr[168].A = HEX_E;  m_cr[168].B = HEX_0;
    m_cr[169].A = HEX_E;  m_cr[169].B = HEX_1;
    m_cr[170].A = HEX_E;  m_cr[170].B = HEX_2;
    m_cr[171].A = HEX_E;  m_cr[171].B = HEX_3;
    // Row - 3
    m_cr[172].A = HEX_F;  m_cr[172].B = HEX_0;
    m_cr[173].A = HEX_F;  m_cr[173].B = HEX_1;
    m_cr[174].A = HEX_F;  m_cr[174].B = HEX_2;
    m_cr[175].A = HEX_F;  m_cr[175].B = HEX_3;

    // Slice - 3
    // Row - 0
    m_cr[176].A = HEX_C;  m_cr[176].B = HEX_4;
    m_cr[177].A = HEX_C;  m_cr[177].B = HEX_5;
    m_cr[178].A = HEX_C;  m_cr[178].B = HEX_6;
    m_cr[179].A = HEX_C;  m_cr[179].B = HEX_7;
    // Row - 1
    m_cr[180].A = HEX_D;  m_cr[180].B = HEX_4;
    m_cr[181].A = HEX_D;  m_cr[181].B = HEX_5;
    m_cr[182].A = HEX_D;  m_cr[182].B = HEX_6;
    m_cr[183].A = HEX_D;  m_cr[183].B = HEX_7;
    // Row - 2;
    m_cr[184].A = HEX_E;  m_cr[184].B = HEX_4;
    m_cr[185].A = HEX_E;  m_cr[185].B = HEX_5;
    m_cr[186].A = HEX_E;  m_cr[186].B = HEX_6;
    m_cr[187].A = HEX_E;  m_cr[187].B = HEX_7;
    // Row - 3
    m_cr[188].A = HEX_F;  m_cr[188].B = HEX_4;
    m_cr[189].A = HEX_F;  m_cr[189].B = HEX_5;
    m_cr[190].A = HEX_F;  m_cr[190].B = HEX_6;
    m_cr[191].A = HEX_F;  m_cr[191].B = HEX_7;

    // BOX - 3
    // Slice - 0
    // Row - 0
    m_cr[192].A = HEX_8;  m_cr[192].B = HEX_8;
    m_cr[193].A = HEX_8;  m_cr[193].B = HEX_9;
    m_cr[194].A = HEX_8;  m_cr[194].B = HEX_A;
    m_cr[195].A = HEX_8;  m_cr[195].B = HEX_B;
    // Row - 1
    m_cr[196].A = HEX_9;  m_cr[196].B = HEX_8;
    m_cr[197].A = HEX_9;  m_cr[197].B = HEX_9;
    m_cr[198].A = HEX_9;  m_cr[198].B = HEX_A;
    m_cr[199].A = HEX_9;  m_cr[199].B = HEX_B;
    // Row - 2
    m_cr[200].A = HEX_A;  m_cr[200].B = HEX_8;
    m_cr[201].A = HEX_A;  m_cr[201].B = HEX_9;
    m_cr[202].A = HEX_A;  m_cr[202].B = HEX_A;
    m_cr[203].A = HEX_A;  m_cr[203].B = HEX_B;
    // Row - 3
    m_cr[204].A = HEX_B;  m_cr[204].B = HEX_8;
    m_cr[205].A = HEX_B;  m_cr[205].B = HEX_9;
    m_cr[206].A = HEX_B;  m_cr[206].B = HEX_A;
    m_cr[207].A = HEX_B;  m_cr[207].B = HEX_B;

    // Slice - 1
    // Row - 0
    m_cr[208].A = HEX_8;  m_cr[208].B = HEX_C;
    m_cr[209].A = HEX_8;  m_cr[209].B = HEX_D;
    m_cr[210].A = HEX_8;  m_cr[210].B = HEX_E;
    m_cr[211].A = HEX_8;  m_cr[211].B = HEX_F;
    // Row - 1
    m_cr[212].A = HEX_9;  m_cr[212].B = HEX_C;
    m_cr[213].A = HEX_9;  m_cr[213].B = HEX_D;
    m_cr[214].A = HEX_9;  m_cr[214].B = HEX_E;
    m_cr[215].A = HEX_9;  m_cr[215].B = HEX_F;
    // Row - 2
    m_cr[216].A = HEX_A;  m_cr[216].B = HEX_C;
    m_cr[217].A = HEX_A;  m_cr[217].B = HEX_D;
    m_cr[218].A = HEX_A;  m_cr[218].B = HEX_E;
    m_cr[219].A = HEX_A;  m_cr[219].B = HEX_F;
    // Row - 3
    m_cr[220].A = HEX_B;  m_cr[220].B = HEX_C;
    m_cr[221].A = HEX_B;  m_cr[221].B = HEX_D;
    m_cr[222].A = HEX_B;  m_cr[222].B = HEX_E;
    m_cr[223].A = HEX_B;  m_cr[223].B = HEX_F;

    // Slice - 2
    // Row - 0
    m_cr[224].A = HEX_C;  m_cr[224].B = HEX_8;
    m_cr[225].A = HEX_C;  m_cr[225].B = HEX_9;
    m_cr[226].A = HEX_C;  m_cr[226].B = HEX_A;
    m_cr[227].A = HEX_C;  m_cr[227].B = HEX_B;
    // Row - 1
    m_cr[228].A = HEX_D;  m_cr[228].B = HEX_8;
    m_cr[229].A = HEX_D;  m_cr[229].B = HEX_9;
    m_cr[230].A = HEX_D;  m_cr[230].B = HEX_A;
    m_cr[231].A = HEX_D;  m_cr[231].B = HEX_B;
    // Row - 2
    m_cr[232].A = HEX_E;  m_cr[232].B = HEX_8;
    m_cr[233].A = HEX_E;  m_cr[233].B = HEX_9;
    m_cr[234].A = HEX_E;  m_cr[234].B = HEX_A;
    m_cr[235].A = HEX_E;  m_cr[235].B = HEX_B;
    // Row - 3
    m_cr[236].A = HEX_F;  m_cr[236].B = HEX_8;
    m_cr[237].A = HEX_F;  m_cr[237].B = HEX_9;
    m_cr[238].A = HEX_F;  m_cr[238].B = HEX_A;
    m_cr[239].A = HEX_F;  m_cr[239].B = HEX_B;

    // Slice - 3
    // Row - 0
    m_cr[240].A = HEX_C;  m_cr[240].B = HEX_C;
    m_cr[241].A = HEX_C;  m_cr[241].B = HEX_D;
    m_cr[242].A = HEX_C;  m_cr[242].B = HEX_E;
    m_cr[243].A = HEX_C;  m_cr[243].B = HEX_F;
    // Row - 1
    m_cr[244].A = HEX_D;  m_cr[244].B = HEX_C;
    m_cr[245].A = HEX_D;  m_cr[245].B = HEX_D;
    m_cr[246].A = HEX_D;  m_cr[246].B = HEX_E;
    m_cr[247].A = HEX_D;  m_cr[247].B = HEX_F;
    // Row - 2
    m_cr[248].A = HEX_E;  m_cr[248].B = HEX_C;
    m_cr[249].A = HEX_E;  m_cr[249].B = HEX_D;
    m_cr[250].A = HEX_E;  m_cr[250].B = HEX_E;
    m_cr[251].A = HEX_E;  m_cr[251].B = HEX_F;
    // Row - 3
    m_cr[252].A = HEX_F;  m_cr[252].B = HEX_C;
    m_cr[253].A = HEX_F;  m_cr[253].B = HEX_D;
    m_cr[254].A = HEX_F;  m_cr[254].B = HEX_E;
    m_cr[255].A = HEX_F;  m_cr[255].B = HEX_F;

} // initializeCrossReference
```

As you can see this function is long, and not very readable. I'm trying to figure out a way to implement this function in an elegant manner and this is where I am stuck. How would I generate this pattern within in few lines of code using for loop/s and a few if statements(if needed)?

Eventually I would like to compress these [A,B] coordinates into a single unsigned char as if [A,B] = [0x0C,0x08] it would be stored as 0xC8 as a byte instead of a pair of enumerations.

**EDIT** - Adding a new Image that should help to understand how I am generating my coordinate pairs and the exact order that they must be in within my look up array.

[image: Improved Image]

**Note:** This question is the post that I'm accepting, and as for the old question here [Custom Data Structure: Implementing an algorithim to generate a lookup table [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415462/custom-data-structure-implementing-an-algorithim-to-generate-a-lookup-table) is now a dead post, please refer to this one as being the correct one. I was having trouble with my browser last night when I tried to continue to edit the old one. I was planning on deleting it but I will leave it there for historical purposes and let the administration determine whether or not to delete it.

Comment: Start by changing `HEX_` to an array. Then, look at individual blocks and turn them into loops. See then if you can make a more general method.

Comment: Also, since your `.A` and `.B` are not dependent upon each other, you can do this process separately for each.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq yes; I kind of understand that and I've tried going through loops but when I complete one slice to go to the next or when I complete one box going to the next is where I'm getting stuck.

Comment: Maybe for my 2nd Image I can reproduce it as a larger image, and add a little more detail to show the traversal of the grid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Data Structure: Implementing an algorithim to generate a lookup table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415462/custom-data-structure-implementing-an-algorithim-to-generate-a-lookup-table)

Comment: @jbapple Yes, however this is the valid  question, the old one is no longer active and is considered dead. I was having trouble with my browser last night when I tried to edit the old one.

Comment: Both Anton Savin and Sam Varshavchik provided answers with an algorithm that produces the correct values, and both of their calculations have different implementations. I gave Anton Savin the answer to this question due to the fact that he was the first one to provide an answer that yielded the correct results. It doesn't have anything to do with which implementation is better as I will leave that for a completely new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
    int cube = i / 64;
    int slice = (i % 64) / 16;
    int row = (i % 16) / 4;
    int col = i % 4;
    m_cr[i].A = cube / 2 * 8 + slice / 2 * 4 + row;
    m_cr[i].B = cube % 2 * 8 + slice % 2 * 4 + col;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking the effort to figure out the calculations and the time to remove it from the old question and posting it here to this one. I think where I went wrong in my initial attempts was I did not think to use the modulus operator in the calculation. And now that I have this available I can move on with my project. Now that the algorithm is in place, I can change the array from a struct of two enumerations and use two byte data types (unsigned char) then compress them into one byte using bit manipulation. Thank you so much for this, I've been at this for almost a week.

Comment: @FrancisCugler no problem, glad it helped.

Comment: It took me several hours just to write up the question never mind creating the graphics using MS paint and this was after hours of trying to work this out. I've tried single for loop, double for loops, and quad for loops, using intermediate counters etc. and after several days of trying I came here hoping to get this one function working so I can move on with the rest of the data structure.

Answer (score 2):

Having stared at the lookup table, for a few minutes (and only at the raw data in the lookup table, I couldn't follow the graphics), I believe that the following example will generate your lookup table.

As I told you [in your first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36415462/custom-data-structure-implementing-an-algorithim-to-generate-a-lookup-table), most of the question is irrelevant. If you got rid of the first 3/4th of your question, someone would've probably came up with an answer soon. Sometimes it does help to know a little bit of what the data means, but here it seems to be more of a distraction, than anything else.

Anyway, the first thing to do is to get rid of the `enum`. It doesn't add any value, and just gets in the way. Just use natural hexadecimal numbers, that's all. Having said that, it should be trivial for you to adapt this with your own code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    for (int n=0; n<256; ++n)
    {
        int a = ((((n >> 5) & 1) << 2) | (n & 0x80) >> 4) | ((n >> 2) & 3);
        int b = (n & 3) | (((n >> 4) & 1) << 2) |
            (((n >> 6) & 1) << 3);

        std::cout << n << ": a=" << a << " b=" << b << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I have a nagging feeling that this can be simplified a little bit even more, perhaps someone else can contribute an improvement, but, in any case, the output from this seems to match the raw hexadecimal values, for both `A` and `B`, in your lookup table.

Comment: The first image shows the starting location at the top left: `arr[0][0][0][0]` move left and it is `arr[0][0][0][1]`  hence `arr[box][slice][row][col]` From the top left we move right until idx = 3, then we move down to next row and until row, col is [3][3]. Then we move back to the next slice and repeat this until slice's idx = 3. Once we are at [0][3][3][3] we move to the next box and repeat the process. The first image is only showing 1 cube or box. The second image is taking the full 4x4x4x4 array laying it out in a 16x16 array...

Comment: (...continued) if you look at the numbers above and to the left of the box that are not in hex value in the second image these numbers going across are the index values of the 4x4x4x4 array; as you can see they repeat 0,1,2,3. The numbers in hex value are the numbers I want to use as coordinates within the cross reference table. The square is divided into four quadrants Top Left, Top Right, Bottom Left & Bottom Right. Each one of these four sections represents which box we are in. These indexes are labeled in grey text. These would be `array[0][][][], [1][][][], [2][][][], [3][][][]`...

Comment: (...continued) Each of these four boxes are also divided into four quadrants with the same pattern TR, TL, BR, BL. And the index value of these would be `array[][0][][], array[][1][][], array[][2][], array[][3][][]`.

Comment: I was checking out the output in my console; and everything was fine up until index value 31. Starting at index value 32 the A is correct but the B is wrong. The B is out outputting 8,9,10,11 repeating and it should be 0,1,2,3. Index 32 - 47 is slice index 2 which is the third slice of box 0. These values should be: [4,0 - 3], [5, 0 - 3], [6, 0 - 3], [7, 0 - 3].

Comment: Made a small adjustment, should line up now.

Comment: I will check out your adjustment, however the answer Anton Savin provided does work correctly. I  appreciate your effort. If you calculations work correctly then I'll up vote it to remove the down vote.

Comment: I originally accepted Anton Savin's answer since he was the first to come up with an algorithm to display the correct results, however, in the end it was your algorithm that I ended up using. With your bitwise operations it processes at about 40% faster than Anton's. The modulus and addition operations shouldn't be to much over head but what I think makes his slower is the division's that have to take place on each iteration. I might have to sit down with a ledger and do the math for each iteration of your algorithm to kind of get an understanding of how you came up with it. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Start by changing HEX_ to an array. Then, look at individual blocks and turn them into loops. Since your `.A` and `.B` are mutually exclusive, we may handle them separately.

Here's a "function" you may use to help initialize A:

```
void InitializeA(CrossReference arr[])
{
    InitializeABlock(arr, 0x00, 0x00);
    InitializeABlock(arr, 0x10, 0x00);
    InitializeABlock(arr, 0x20, 0x04);
    InitializeABlock(arr, 0x30, 0x04);
    InitializeABlock(arr, 0x40, 0x00);
    InitializeABlock(arr, 0x50, 0x00);
    InitializeABlock(arr, 0x60, 0x04);
    InitializeABlock(arr, 0x70, 0x04);

    InitializeABlock(arr, 0x80, 0x08);
    InitializeABlock(arr, 0x90, 0x08);
    InitializeABlock(arr, 0xA0, 0x10);
    InitializeABlock(arr, 0xB0, 0x10);
    InitializeABlock(arr, 0xC0, 0x08);
    InitializeABlock(arr, 0xD0, 0x08);
    InitializeABlock(arr, 0xE0, 0x10);
    InitializeABlock(arr, 0xF0, 0x10);
}

void InitializeABlock(CrossReference arr[], int idxStart, int hexStart)
{
    for(int j = hexStart; j < hexStart + 4; j++)
    {
        int baseIdx = idxStart + 4 * (j - hexStart);

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            arr[baseIdx + i].A = j;
        }
    }
}
```

The implementation for B is very similar:

```
void InitializeB(CrossReference arr[])
{
    InitializeBBlock(arr, 0x00, 0x00);
    InitializeBBlock(arr, 0x10, 0x00);
    InitializeBBlock(arr, 0x20, 0x04);
    InitializeBBlock(arr, 0x30, 0x04);
    InitializeBBlock(arr, 0x40, 0x00);
    InitializeBBlock(arr, 0x50, 0x00);
    InitializeBBlock(arr, 0x60, 0x04);
    InitializeBBlock(arr, 0x70, 0x04);

    InitializeBBlock(arr, 0x80, 0x08);
    InitializeBBlock(arr, 0x90, 0x08);
    InitializeBBlock(arr, 0xA0, 0x10);
    InitializeBBlock(arr, 0xB0, 0x10);
    InitializeBBlock(arr, 0xC0, 0x08);
    InitializeBBlock(arr, 0xD0, 0x08);
    InitializeBBlock(arr, 0xE0, 0x10);
    InitializeBBlock(arr, 0xF0, 0x10);
}

void InitializeBBlock(CrossReference arr[], int idxStart, int hexStart)
{
    for(int j = idxStart; j < idxStart + 4; j++)
    {
        int baseIdx = idxStart + 4 * (j - idxStart);

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            arr[baseIdx + i].A = i + hexStart;
        }
    }
}
```

You may, of course, compress this further. ;)

Comment: I think you are miss understanding the A & B. A & B are not each individual pairs. A is going down the structure while B is going across the structure. Think of A as being y and B as being x in Cartesian coordinates.