# Designing a lookup map

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a problem on designing a proper mapping.

i'm developing a top-down rpg game where you only see parts (chunks) of the map at runtime - when moving from one chunk to to another the new chunk data is loaded.

depending on my position different data is loaded.

currently looks my code like this (but certainly longer)

```
public static final int getChunkIdForPos(int x, int y){
    switch (x) {                    
    case 1248:  
        switch (y) {
        case 1247: return R.raw.overworld_512;
        case 1248: return R.raw.overworld_528;
        case 1249: return R.raw.overworld_544;
        default: break;}break;          
    case 1249:  
        switch (y) {
        case 1247: return R.raw.overworld_513;
        case 1248: return R.raw.overworld_529;
        case 1249: return R.raw.overworld_545;
        default: break;}break;
    }
    return R.raw.overworld_161;
}
```

problem is that this code is **not easy to read** and **not easy to maintain**. Any Ideas on how to do better?

i was thinking about using `Map<Integer,<Map<Integer,Integer>>` to map data but that requires to create the Map first. That also means you carry lots of 'dead' objects as keys around (same for `SparseArray<SparseArray<>>`)

Note: you can not determinate the returned values by any Math as suggested in this [answer - Implemention a Lookup Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36416290/implementing-a-lookup-table)

the reason for choosing this design is to get an answer without creating any objects - the lookup just runs through two switch/case statements and provides an answer on the fly!

Comment: If you used a map, how many "dead" keys would you expect to have?

Comment: what about encapsulate reachable map's blocks in each map block?

Comment: i was thinking of a map of 10.000 x 10.000 chunks at least

Comment: the idea was that map chunks can be provided by other players and help to create parts of the world

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, first things first: I limited the map from 10.000x10.000 to 256x256

- still the code is not maintainable!
- still the code is not extendable!
- still best performance is using switch/case

the proper way to handle this is using a **code generator**. In a seperate project, thats not limited I create a worldmap-editor, that lets me see the all chunks in combination. Once the map is complete (hint: you can save/load maps now) the code emitter generates a class for you.

[image: Chunk editor]

the magic is done from the codeEmitter class:

```
int[][] worldMap = new int[256][256]; //generated via GUI
File file = new File(fileName);
BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));

//writing header

for (int dy = 0; dy < 256; dy++) {
    br.write("    public static int row_"+dy+"(int x){\n");
    br.write("        switch (x) {\n");
    for (int dx = 0; dx < 256; dx++) {
        br.write("        case " + dx + ": return " + worldMap[dx][dy] + ";\n");
    }
    br.write("        default: return 0;\n");
    br.write("        }\n");
    br.write("    }\n");
    br.write("\n");
}

//writing trailer
```

the result is very similar to the requested code from the question

```
 //this part of genCode is not explained above
 public static final int getIdForPos(int x, int y, int area){
    switch (y) {
    case 0: return row_0(x);
    case 1: return row_1(x);
    //.. lots of rows
    default: return 0;
    }
 }

 //but this part is generated with the code above
 public static int row_0(int x){
    switch (x) {
    case 0: return 4711;
    case 1: return 815;
    //.. lots of columns
    default: return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `Point` class with `equals` and `hashcode` implemented you can use them as keys in maps.

Now the actual lookup mechanism collapses to:

```
static final Map<Point, Integer> lookup = new HashMap<>();

static {
    // Looks a lot like your case statement eh?
    lookup.put(new Point(1248, 1247), 512);
    lookup.put(new Point(1248, 1248), 528);
    lookup.put(new Point(1248, 1249), 544);
    lookup.put(new Point(1249, 1247), 513);
    lookup.put(new Point(1249, 1248), 529);
    lookup.put(new Point(1249, 1249), 545);
    // Could also be populated by other statics.
}

public static final int getChunkIdForPos(int x, int y) {
    Integer got = lookup.get(new Point(x, y));
    return got != null ? got : 161;
}
```

The elegance of this is that the map is only ever built once. It is built at a predictable time (first reference to the class) and it can be added to by other modules (through a little tweaking).

Here's an example of a `Point` class that correctly implements `equals` and `hashcode`.

```
public static class Point {

    final int x;
    final int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + x + "," + y + '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 97 * hash + this.x;
        hash = 97 * hash + this.y;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Point other = (Point) obj;
        if (this.x != other.x) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.y != other.y) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: if i use the switch-statement as described in my question **no objects** are created, the result is grabbed on the fly - I can't think of any way to achive this better, but this definitely would clean up my code.

Comment: @MartinFrank - Java is designed to handle objects efficiently so unless you are working in some embedded environment or a low-memory situation the cost is negligible. The value is the saving in programmer time at cost of a little memory. NB: `static` initialisation happens only once.

Comment: @MartinFrank - The `case` method does inded approach minimal time cost but a `HashMap` lookup is `O(1)` and very close in speed.

Comment: it's an android app and my designed to work on older devices (Android2.3)... this is the very reason why i even think about

Comment: i think the matters **clean code** and **maintainance** would be the reason to choose your solution, even if i am not sure if there is a better way...  (gimme a day or so and i'll accept it)

Comment: can you remove the `point` implementation - that one done as well as it does not provide any hints (expect that you have to know that hash&equals is required to define unique keys)

Comment: @MartinFrank - I've moved `Point` down to the end, hope that's acceptable.

Comment: uhm - i have to give up - 10.000 x 10.000 is not an option any more.... i think i'll limit the map to 100x100 chunks and have therefore some layers....

Comment: i cannot accept your answer because i'll move the map into txt-files and generate the java code from the txt-file... that way i have an easy way to maintain the map data and have no longer to care about the code itself

Comment: even though not provided the proper answer it helped to narrow down a solution thats acceptable for me! thank you very much!